# Nativescrit TexField focus

Tags: nativescript

I'm battling to make the textfield when selected to be above the keyboard:

Tried this code:

HTML:

```html
<StackLayout class="input-field">
      <Label text="Postal Code" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5"
      </Label>
     <TextField #postalCode id="postalCode" (tap)="onFocus()" 
     [(ngModel)]="model.address.postal_code" class="input" ></TextField>
</StackLayout>
```

TS:

```js
onFocus() {
    let postalCode = <TextField> this.postalCode.nativeElement;
    console.log(postalCode.focus());
 }
```

Comment: **"*when selected to be above the keyboard*"** huh? No clue what you're at...

Comment: Is this for a mobile phone view where keyboard pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push the textfield up when the keyboard is selected, open `App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml` and add this to the `<activity`: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`.